# Request multiply parameters

Tags: java, spring, httprequest

I got a  problem regarding request.getParameterMap()

In my jspx file multiply parameters are added when the user selects items out 
of a table. now that i want to get them in my Controller
with request.getParameterMap(); it doesnt work with Firefox, Safari 
but it works fine with chrome

anyone has an idea why it is so ?

---

thx for the replies .. the html form with the request parameters is build dynamicly at runtime using javascript, which seems to cause problems with widged based browsers like safari, firefox and most likely IE.

i will use ajax to get it work

Comment: I am not clear with your words. acc to me, There is no connection between browser and server side things like *request.getParameterMap()* each browser sends request in same manner. Very strange question.!!

Comment: If there is a difference between browsers, either it is an issue with character encoding, or the HTML form is not HTML conform. Especially if you are using strict XHTML or so, different browsers may repair the HTML differently. Or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the way that you are getting the parameter values from the map.  It cannot be.  The problem has to be in the HTML / Javascript / whatever that is creating the request on the client (browser) side.

It is most likely that you are doing something that is not strictly HTML (or whatever) compliant.  Some browsers are treating it one way, and others another way.  I suggest that you start by running an HTML validator over the page.

Answer (score 0):

browser is not aware of request.getParameterMap() or any method in servlet api.

In your use case : you have a table of data , out of which user may select some rows and you need this data in server side for some action on those rows.

For eg : mark as read in GMAIL

select one or more rows in gmail and click ,mark as read will sent some request to google server and get those rows marked as read by user.

You can do it this way, you need to send primary key of your rows to server side with same parameter name
for eg: /delete?delId=1&delId=3&delId=7

and use request.getParameterValues() in server side to retrieve a list of ids to be deleted.